# How to prove user's presence in certain place using only qr-code and internet?

Tags: qr-code

I need to prove user's presence in certain place using only qr code,  and text user's id. Based on this I need to form and sent a request to web site, increasing his rating.

Writing mobile app is not an option, changing qr code or making it dynamic is also not an option, using gps is also not an option.

Usecase:
User comes to a special place, where qr code is placed. 
User scans qr code and is redirected to web site.
User enters his text ID and gets a flag in database, proving that he visited place.

Main concern: how to avoid passing qr code and getting flag in database from user who visited place to user who didn't visit place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to prove user's presence in certain place using only qr-code and internet?

With the limitations you've mentioned (no mobile app, no GPS, ..) you can't prove anything.

*Usecase: A user's friend goes to a special place where a QR Code is placed and broadcasts the URL for the web site on social media. 600 different users see the URL on social media, go to the web site and enter their text ID; and those 600 users get a flag in database proving that they visited place even though none of them ever did.*

Without one of the limitations, you still can't prove anything. For example, 600 users can email their text ID to a single "non-user", and that "non-user" can stand in front of an extremely quickly changing QR Code and make you think that 600 users were present when they weren't. For another example, 600 users can give their smartphone (with a special mobile app installed) to a single "non-user", and that "non-user" can let the app running on each user's smartphone upload GPS coordinates and make you think that 600 users were present when they weren't.

The only way to prove a user's presence is to obtain evidence that the user (and not their smartphone and not an impostor) was at the location. For example, have some kind of "secure machine" at the location that uses bio-metrics (e.g., finger print scanner maybe).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution. It's Google Authenticator. Visitor, who wants to get a 'stamp' for visiting some place goes to special web page. Web page asks for code. This code can be acquired from a person working on place visited and send to website.